# Can I retrieve the full history of commands from a Perl pdl2 shell (like history in bash)?

Tags: perl, pdl

I am using pdl2 shell, how can I list all my commands history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find your history in $HOME/.perldl_hist

This may or may not be dependent on having Term::ReadLine::Gnu installed (which I have by default).

If you want access to your history within `pdl`, then just use the up arrow key for the previous commands, or type ^R (control-r) then a text that you want to search back for (hitting ^r repeatedly for matches further back).

```
$ pdl
perlDL shell v1.354
...blah blah blah...
pdl> print 1+1
2
pdl> print 2+2
4
pdl> quit

$ cat ~/.perldl_hist 
print 1+1
print 2+2
$
```

**EDIT**:  To find the history from *within* `pdl`, do the following:

```
$ pdl
pdl> print join "\n", $PERLDL::TERM->GetHistory
```

The `$PERLDL::TERM->GetHistory` returns an array of the current history.  It's just a regular array, so you can do whatever you like with it.  For example, to find all of your recent histogram operations involving a piddle named `mypdl`, you could do:

```
pdl> print join "\n", grep { /histogram/ && /mypdl/ } $PERLDL::TERM->GetHistory
```

Comment: thanks. I forgot about the hist file. I wanted to list the history inside pdl2 to find out what I have done previously before keep going coding and forgot about the posibility of `^z cat...`. Well next time if I really want to see it inside pdl2 I can always do `pdl> print qx{cat ~/.perldl_hist}`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I want to see the history of my current session without quitting!!. Is that possible? The current session history is only added to .perldl_hist after quitting.

Comment: @Pablo - I've updated the answer to get the information from within `pdl`.  Please note, you have to have either `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` (preferred) or `Term::ReadLine::Perl` installed.

Answer (score 2):

From the PDL documentation (i.e., `pdldoc perldl`):

```
History mechanism
  If you have the perl modules ReadLines and ReadKeys installed, then
  perldl supports a history and line-editing mechanism using editing keys
  similar to emacs. The last 500 commands are always stored in the file
  .perldl_hist in your home directory between sessions. Set
  $PERLDL::HISTFILESIZE to change the number of lines saved. The command
  "l [number]" shows you the last "number" commands you typed where
  "number" defaults to 20.
```

Comment: After developing a computational approach in the `pdl2` shell, you can copy the .perldl_hist file and edit to generate a script/program to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `l` command lists your history if you have a suitable `readline` installed.